# why am i getting ' event processing lagging behind' msg in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xorg, gdm

seeing my system logs, they are full of msgs like this:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2564]: (EE) event4  - SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 25ms, your system is too slow
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2564]: (EE) event4  - SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 17ms, your system is too slow
```

i have a 12 core system which is essentially idle when i see this. it seems to happen since i upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10.

how can i find the root cause and how to eliminate this issue?

sys info:

```
model name  : AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy10/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor:ondemand
```

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/available_governors:ladder menu teo 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver:acpi_idle
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_governor:menu
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_governor_ro:menu
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding: Processor make and model; CPU frequency scaling driver and governor; Idle governor. Do: `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_driver`; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor`; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/*`.

Comment: ok, i added what you asked

Comment: It might have to do with this, although I am not sure: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend

Comment: I'm actually getting the same thing on a Lenovo desktop with i7-8700 with sway & wayland. But they some wayland windows (alacritty) stop working. Actually the whole thing stops working but killing swayidle from another VT and running swaymsg reload in a new terminal kills the old windows.

Answer (score 3):

That error message is not from the kernel, and is somewhat misleading. It isn't even really an error, more a warning. Some think that it should say:

```
your compositor is too slow
```

instead of

```
your system is too slow
```

Ignore it.

References:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1117556-start-0.html
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=968093

Comment: I cannot ignore it, my keybinds are not being recognized correctly. It is very frustrating. Super + A hotkey is registered as just A.

Comment: Same issue: media keys all stopped working a few weeks ago, as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1454998/296551). I too see this message.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've seen on machines that have an Nvidia graphics card installed. In my case, the driver was out of date and an update resolved the issue (as well as a frame-dropping issue that had developed after upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04). My CPU is a lot slower than your Ryzen, but this could be an area to examine.

Comment: I have an Intel (integrated) graphics card on my laptop, and I've plenty of such messages. I think my drivers are pretty recent, because it's Arch Linux (rolling release).

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko Same here, i7-8700, always latest Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here.

CPU:
model name : AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor

An update form nvidia driver 390X to 460.73.01 was the first step.
Thx to @user1091774

The bluetooth connection was still laggy so i switch to the Unified dongle.

Maybe this has some effect too:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

The errors in log are gone.