# Ubuntu 22.04LTS media keys stopped working

Tags: keyboard, volume-control

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04LTS Desktop for over a year now (on a Ryzen 9 5950X, which is awesome, but I don't think that matters).

The specific version is:

```shell
sudo dmesg | head -1 | fmt -w 80
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-60-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-054)
(gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu)
2.38) #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-60.66-generic
5.15.78)
```

All of a sudden a few weeks ago, probably as a result of some auto-update, the media keys (volume up/down, pause/continue, mute, next song/prev song, etc.) have stopped working altogether. The keyboard is a [Microsoft Keyboard 4000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ergonomic_keyboards#Natural_Ergonomic_Keyboard_4000), with dedicated media keys (no key combinations e.g. Fn+...).

I've looked at similar questions, but they seem quite old. The most recent answers I found include [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407486/296551) and [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1435785/296551). Both recommend restarting `pipe-session-manager`, but it did nothing to help the situation. On the contrary, it entirely shut down all my audio, and after various attempts to "nicely" revive it, I had to reboot.

What can I do to even diagnose the problem?

FWIW, I tried to monitor events via [`evtest`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/evtest.1.html), tried all 5 devices with a name containing `Microsoft_KM-V1.a`, but I cannot see any event triggered when I press any of the media keys.

**Edit** When looking at `journalctl --since today | tail` just after hitting a few of the media keys, I see the puzzling message:

```
..... /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[10302]: (EE) event2  - Microsoft_KM-V1.a: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 37ms, your system is too slow
```

It is puzzling because the specs of that machine are quite good and it is lightning fast (see the [Geekbench 6 results](https://browser.geekbench.com/v6/cpu/98073)).

Comment: I'd look at what actually changed when the keyboard stopped working as you wanted... ie. if I note a change that was *unexpected* esp. after reboot/login compared to prior session, I explore the system logs & what updated during the last session for changes.  Did you look? I assume this is a desktop system (*you didn't actually specify what 22.04*) where a recent change for systems using the HWE kernel was from 5.15 to 5.19 kernel; did you explore if that's why?  Did you boot an older kernel at grub & it works again?  If so that may give you an alternative (use GA kernel stack) or more info...

Comment: Added specific os version. It would be great if I could pinpoint when exactly it stopped working. No such luck, as I am often on the move. The best I can figure out is that it stopped working within the last 6 weeks or so.  Isn't there a way to diagnose what may be happening? I've pored over `/var/log/syslog` etc. but no luck.

Comment: Same issue for me; I upgraded from 20.04 and was then unable to use my keyboard media keys. Even trying to bind it does not work.